# Multiply the price by qty in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble multiplying the price and the quantity and calculating the output inside an input in my asp .net mvc project. I seem to get only the first row of the table to do so and the others that follow won't display anything. As you can see I am appending a table and its contents using javascript. Please find a way to do so for the remaining rows. The function that does the calculation is multiply() deep down, I have pasted the rest for your convenience.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
var date = document.getElementById('second');
date.setAttribute('type', 'date');
var inp = document.getElementById('last');
inp.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addRow();
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("addRow").click();
    }
});
var box = document.getElementById('second');
box.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        addRow();
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("addRow").click();
    }
});

function addRow() {
    var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
    var rowCnt = empTab.rows.length;   // table row count.
    var tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt); // the table row.
    tr = empTab.insertRow(rowCnt);
    // as you can see there are 5 rows

    for (var c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
        var td = document.createElement('td'); // table definition.
        td = tr.insertCell(c);
        if (c == 0) {
            var html = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-danger" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
            td.innerHTML = html;
        }
        else if (c == 1) {
            var htnl = '<select class="form-control"><option>dead</option><option>byr</option></select>'
            td.innerHTML = htnl;
        }
        else if (c == 2) {
            var qty = document.createElement('input');
            qty.className = "form-control";
            qty.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            qty.setAttribute('id', 'qty');
            qty.setAttribute('onkeypress', 'javascript: if(event.keyCode === 13) addRow(this);');
            qty.setAttribute('oninput', 'multiply(this)');
            td.appendChild(qty);
        }
        else if (c == 3) {
            var rate = document.createElement('input');
            rate.className = "form-control";
            rate.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            rate.setAttribute('id', 'rate');
            rate.setAttribute('onkeypress', 'javascript: if(event.keyCode === 13) addRow(this);');
            rate.setAttribute('oninput', 'multiply(this)');
            td.appendChild(rate);
        }
        else if (c == 4) {
            var total = document.createElement('input');
            total.className = "form-control";
            total.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            total.disabled = false;
            total.setAttribute('id', 'total');
            total.setAttribute('onkeypress', 'javascript: if(event.keyCode === 13) addRow(this);');
            td.appendChild(total);
        }
    }
}
function multiply() {
        var inpTotal = document.getElementById('qty').value || 0;
        var inpRate = document.getElementById('rate').value || 0;
        var product = parseFloat(inpTotal) * parseFloat(inpRate);
        document.getElementById('total').value = product;
        return (product);
}

// delete TABLE row function.
function removeRow(oButton) {
    var empTab = document.getElementById('empTable');
    empTab.deleteRow(oButton.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex); // button -> td -> tr.
}

// function to extract and submit table data.
```

Comment: well, it is more easier to understand if you can post a small demo or the output view. but looks like you're creating dynamic elements with the same id (qty, rate, total). in HTML, id attribute has to be unique per element, so this is not good. When you multiply them, you fetch it based on the id, so only first match will be fetched every time. You need to add a class on each element (qty, rate, total) and fetch your values based on that. In multiply function, you need to get the parent row and find elements by class within that parent only.

Comment: You are using the same id in every row